# Firebase data missing from child_added snapshot when inside callback for child value change event

Tags: firebase

I encountered this problem when trying to display all user data (including the current user) to the user once they "activated" their account.  When listening to an onValue change for an item in a list, then listening in the callback to the child_added event for the list, data is missing from the snapshot of the originally "watched" item.

Contrived reproduction:

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var rootRef = new Firebase('YOUR-FIREBASE-URL');

var userListRef = rootRef.child('users');

// Clearing the list
userListRef.remove();

// Create a list of users with at least two key/values
var firstUserRef = userListRef.push({name: 'me', active: false});
userListRef.push({name: 'you', active: false});
userListRef.push({name: 'someone', active: false});

// listen for a change to one of the users child data
firstUserRef.child('active').once('value', function(activeData){

    // When the value change callback fires list all of the users data
    userListRef.on('child_added', function(userData){
        console.log(userData.val());
    })

});
```

Console Output:

```
{ active: false }
{ active: false, name: 'you' }
{ active: false, name: 'someone' }
```

Where did the name data go? This doesn't seem like expected behavior, or a syncing issue because the name data should already be set locally. If we modify the code to retrieve the entire list object like this:

```
// listen for a change to one of the users child data
firstUserRef.child('active').once('value', function(activeData){

    // When the value change callback fires list all of the users data
    userListRef.on('value', function(usersData){
        console.log(usersData.val());
    })

});
```

All of the data is included:

```
{ '-J1ayCVS6B_zVterQWJh': { active: false, name: 'me' },
  '-J1ayCVUUAFP0TL77oaO': { active: false, name: 'you' },
  '-J1ayCVUUAFP0TL77oaP': { active: false, name: 'someone' } }
```

Anybody know whats going on here?

Comment: Hey @A-Five, I'm unable to reproduce this issue. I just ran your code and I got the expected response. Is this issue still occurring? Can you check to see if you're on the latest version of Firebase via npm?

Comment: Hi @Anant, Just confirmed issue is still happening.  Using Node: v0.10.15 and Firebase: 0.6.3 on OSX 10.8.4.  Also, installed Node v0.10.20 binary and gave it a shot, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong you attach an event into another event.. there is no need...

example :

```
cars (parent node)
----- -J1ayCVS6B_zVterQWJh
----- -J1ayCVUUAFP0TL77oaO
----- -J1ayCVUUAFP0TL77oaP
```

to grab the changes

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://g.com/cars");

ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.val() != null) {

        snapshot.forEach(function(itemDetails) {
            itemDetails.val().username;
            itemDetails.val().active;
        });
    }
});


//and to be serious first attach the event, then you push the records
//assume is a button_click 
var ref2 = new Firebase('https://g.com/cars");

var firstUserRef = ref2.push({name: 'me', active: false});
firstUserRef.push({name: 'you', active: false});
firstUserRef .push({name: 'someone', active: false});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but it doesn't solve the problem.  I am aware that there are other ways to get a desired result for the code  I posted, it is a very contrived example of a situation I ran into that was much more complex but I isolated the issue to the example code above.  My question is,  shouldn't the original code I posted still work as I expected it to?  Is it a Firebase bug, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: y, that is true, as I said before 
*1*you cant embed an event to event
*2*first attach the event then do the push 


so if you like @ event to call other http://pastebin.com/rNp77hA4